# prisma isn't applying changes after prisma deploy

Tags: graphql, prisma

I have updated some types in my data model, and upon running `$prisma deploy` it shows that the changes have been made.  However, the playground does not reflect this and upon running `$prisma deploy` again, it re-updates the same changes.

ie I am getting this message again and again, leading me to believe that my updates aren't saving.

datamodel.prisma

```
type User {
  id: ID! @id
  name: String!
  email: String! @unique
  posts: [Post!]!
  comments: [Comment!]!

}

type Post {
  id: ID! @id
  title: String! 
  body: String!
  published: Boolean! 
  author: User!
  comments: [Comment!]!
}

type Comment {
    id: ID! @id
    text: String!
    author: User!
    post: Post!
  }
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.34
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "4466:4466"
    environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 4466
        # uncomment the next line and provide the env var PRISMA_MANAGEMENT_API_SECRET=my-secret to activate cluster security
        # managementApiSecret: my-secret

        databases:
          default:
            connector: postgres
            host: ec2-34-192-30-15.compute-1.amazonaws.com
            database: dcpap3nn15tguo
            schema: public
            user: qlhncorhibvkbb
            password: 273ef84b6ff75904084504c354f92879a036c887dfa4f688cdfaaf12f4e6c30d
            ssl: true
            rawAccess: true
            port: '5432'
            migrations: true
```

prisma.yml

```
endpoint: http://localhost:4466
datamodel: datamodel.prisma
```

and the terminal message every time I run `$prisma deploy`

```
Deploying service `default` to stage `default` to server `local` 6.4s

Changes:

  User (Type)
  ~ Updated field `email`. It became unique.
  + Created field `posts` of type `[Post!]!`
  + Created field `comments` of type `[Comment!]!`

  Post (Type)
  + Created type `Post`
  + Created field `id` of type `ID!`
  + Created field `title` of type `String!`
  + Created field `body` of type `String!`
  + Created field `published` of type `Boolean!`
  + Created field `author` of type `User!`
  + Created field `comments` of type `[Comment!]!`

  Comment (Type)
  + Created type `Comment`
  + Created field `id` of type `ID!`
  + Created field `text` of type `String!`
  + Created field `author` of type `User!`
  + Created field `post` of type `Post!`

  PostToUser (Relation)
  + Created an inline relation between `Post` and `User` in the column `author` of table `Post`

  CommentToUser (Relation)
  + Created an inline relation between `Comment` and `User` in the column `author` of table `Comment`

  CommentToPost (Relation)
  + Created an inline relation between `Comment` and `Post` in the column `post` of table `Comment`

Applying changes 23.6s

Your Prisma endpoint is live:

  HTTP:  http://localhost:4466
  WS:    ws://localhost:4466

You can view & edit your data here:

  Prisma Admin: http://localhost:4466/_admin
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into the Migration table in pgAdmin :

```
SELECT * FROM management."Migration"
ORDER BY "projectId" ASC, revision DESC
```

It may be due to an error thrown by postgre which is not shown in the `prisma deploy` output in your console.

For me it was because I set `User.email` to `@unique` but there were already multiple users with the same email, and strangely it wasn't catched, after that postgre wouldn't accept any more migration.

I reported the bug here : https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2675

Answer (score 1):

Been having the same issue for a while. Don't know what the problem is but I managed to pass around it by

> 1. changing the endpoint of prisma in `prisma.yml` from `http://localhost:4466` to `http://locolhost:4466/anylabel/default`
> 2. then run `prisma1 deploy`

This will deploy your app on a new service on your DB.

Then you can view changes for your new model on `http://locolhost:4466/anylabel/default`

(Hope it helps, though I presume you may have found the solution)

Answer (score 0):

Use `prisma1 deploy` that should work